# when using enctype="multipart/form-data" form doesn't post

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm working on an app on ASP.Net MVC 4 and am trying to upload an image in a form. The problem I'm having is that when the form posts, if the `<input type="file"...` is empty (meaning I have not selected a file) the form posts just fine and everything works. However, When I do select a file the form just sits there and does nothing.

At first I thought it was just taking it a while to upload but I have left it for quite some time (file size was 7kb) and nothing. the debugger doesn't even hit the breakpoints at the beginning of the action either. I'm at a loss since I'm quite new to the platform and am still learning every day. Below please find all the relevant code:

the View:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("StaffInformation", "Manager", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", enctype = "multipart/form-data"}))
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
                <div class="control-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.firstName, new { @class = "control-label" })
                    <div class="controls">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.firstName, new { @class = "span12" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.firstName)
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="control-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.lastName, new { @class = "control-label" })
                    <div class="controls">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.lastName, new { @class = "span12" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.lastName)
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="control-group">
                    Staff Photo:
                    <div class="controls">
                        @if (Model.staffImage == null)
                        {
                            @:None
                        }else{
                        <img width="150" height="150" src="@Url.Action("GetImage", "Manager", new { Model.staffProfileID })" /><br />
                        }
                        <input type="file" id="staffImage" name="staffImage" data-provide="fileinput">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-actions">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                    <a href="@Url.Action("dashboard", "manager")" class="btn" type="reset" >Cancel</a>
                </div>
            }
```

The Action:

```
    public ActionResult StaffInformation(StaffInformationViewModel model, HttpPostedFileBase staffImage)
    {
    if (ModelState.IsValid)   //This is where the breakpoint is
        {
            if (staffImage != null) {
                model.imageMimeType = staffImage.ContentType;
                model.staffImage = new byte[staffImage.ContentLength];
                staffImage.InputStream.Read(model.staffImage, 0, staffImage.ContentLength);
            }

            using (var repo = new CompanyInformationRepository(new UniteOfWorkCompanies()))
            {
                var company = repo.FindCompany(User.Identity.Name);

                repo.AddOrUpdateStaff(model, company);
            }

            return RedirectToAction("ManageStaff");
        }
    }
```

I really don't know whats going on and simply the reason I'm using the `enctype = "multipart/form-data"` is because I was reading the "Pro ASP.NET MVC 4" by Adam Freeman and in there they said that it won't work without it. Like I said, I'm quite new and need all the help I can get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to put the `HttpPostedFileBase staffImage` as part of your ViewModel (`StaffInformationViewModel`) - also yes, you need to keep the `enctype = "multipart/form-data"` in the form tag:

```
public class StaffInformationViewModel
{
    // your other properties here ...

    [Required]
    public HttpPostedFileBase StaffImage { get; set; }
}
```

Then in the View:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.StaffImage, new { type = "file" })
```

Then in the Controller:

```
    public ActionResult StaffInformation(StaffInformationViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (model.StaffImage != null)
            {
                // awesome
            }
            // ... more awesome
        }
    }
```

I hope this helps. Let me know if you need more clarifications here on this one ...

Comment: Hi Dimitar, I can't seem to make a property of type HttpPostedFileBase inside my models project. I have tried to add a reference to the system.web.http (which I believe it lives in) but it is still not able to recognize it. My models are in a separate project as my mvc web project.

Comment: Your models can be on a separate project, but I beleive your ViewModels should not (at least that's the general convention), that's why there are ViewModels and Models. Anyway I beleive the HttpPostedFileBase is in System.Web in case you want to reference it.

Comment: ah ok, I thought they would all sit in the same place for organization but like I said, I'm quite new. I have referenced system.web, system.web.http and added a reference to the system.web.Abstractions with no luck. Do I have to include the viewmodel inside my web project for this to work?

Comment: Well in case you want it in your current project (HttpPostedFileBase that is), you need to add System.Web in the references (right click on your project Reference -> Add Reference -> System.Web) then you should be able to get it.

Comment: But yes if you add the ViewModel to your MVC project you should get it Automagically :)

Comment: ok, so I had both assemblies referenced (system.web and system.web.abstractions) but I remembered that vs 2012 sometimes has a problem recognizing the added assemblies until you restart it with the project. I did that and boom its recognized. now on to trying to fix the original issue with your suggestion. be right back with the results

Comment: :) Awesome ! Good luck, mate.

Comment: There was actually another problem as well. I'm submitting another question :)